# Cakephp form in Twitter Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I need help in using Twitter Bootstrap modal with Cakephp 2.4.2 form?

I have tried following in the view:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php echo __('Form title'); ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->create('Person');
                echo $this->Form->input('First name');
                echo $this->Form->input('Last name');
                echo $this->Form->end('Save');
            ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Form gets displayed automatically on load, and that's fine.

I have problems on closing form/modal. 
When user click Save, modal stays open, but control is passed to action in PeopleController as required.
When user closes modal with Cancel, modal closes, but action from PeopleController hasn't been called at all.

I need control to be passed to PeopleController and modals to be closed.

What would be the best approach?

How to post form data to controller on click of the button in modal-footer?

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using. From your code it looks like 1.2. Even in 1.3 you already use `$this->Form`.

Comment: You're correct. I use cakephp 2.4.2 and I forgot to include line $form=$this->Form which I have in the code too. Here I wrote only piece of the code relevant to the question.

Comment: No, you don't map it to $form, you just always use $this->Form. For Twitter Bootstrap in CakePHP see http://slywalker.github.io/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake/

Comment: Nothing about modals at Boost...

Answer (score 1):

The reason your modal doesn't close is because you made it static. Change this

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
```

for this

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

In other words, data-backdrop="static" makes your modal not to close after form submission.
More [info here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: You were very close. I used data-backdrop="static" to prevent modal close on clicking outside the modal, but the same I got with data-backdrop="false", while this later closes on form close, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: What you mean I was very close? I answered exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to hide the bootstrap modal.

Example:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->create('Person', array('action' => 'add'));
            echo $this->Form->input('First name');
            echo $this->Form->input('Last name');
            echo $this->Form->button('Save');
            echo $this->Form->end();
        ?>
```

Otherwise I think your submit may not be rendering correctly